# how do I find the greatest lower bound and the lowest upper bound for a set under a poset

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is the problem I'm working on: 
Find the greatest lower bound and the lowest upper bound of {{a},{a,b,1},{1,2}} under ⊆ on ({a,b,1,2}).
this is what i have so far: 
Lower bounds of S= {{a},{a,b,1},{1,2}}  are {1} and ∅ 
Of the lower bounds on S, {1} is the greatest lower bound
Within the poset ({a,b,1,2}) the upper bounds of S={{a}, {b}, {1}, {2}}

am i doing this correctly so far? and how should i proceed for the least upper bound?

Comment: The partial order you are working with seems to be that of the "subset" relation.  In such a partial order there is a simple recipe to find the greatest lower bound (of a collection of subsets), and an equally simple recipe to find the least upper bound.  Are you familiar with these "constructions"?

Comment: Im not sure what the constructions are

Comment: Think about a simplified version of such problems.  Suppose that there are only two sets involved, $S_1,S_2 \subseteq \{a,b,1,2\}$.  Can you see how to construct the greatest lower bound of $S_1$ and $S_2$?  What are the subsets below (or equal) to $S_1$, and which of these are also below (or equal) to $S_2$?

Comment: is the lower bound {1}, and ∅

Comment: No. If you are repeating the claim from the question, $\{1\}$ is not a subset of $\{a\}$, so not a lower bound.

Comment: what is the simple recipe to find the bounds?

Comment: so then there are no lower bounds because there is nothing in common?

Comment: When there are no elements in common, the empty set $\emptyset$ is the greatest lower bound. The empty set is a subset of every set.

Comment: Oh got it! is the null set also the least upper bound?

Comment: No, it is hardly ever the least upper bound.

Comment: so how do i find the least upper bound?